# Remove older version of application using MSIX Installer

Tags: .net-core, msix

How can I delete the older version of an application before installing the newer released version?

In other words, is there a way to automatically remove "MSIXDemoInstaller_1.0.0.0_Test" file before installing "MSIXDemoInstaller_1.0.1.0_Test" file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special for this, the OS will handle it automatically. Just increase the version when building your new version. When you install it on a machine with the old version the OS will automatically apply it as an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do so however the old file "MSIXDemoInstaller_1.0.0.0_Test" is never deleted automatically.